# Managing Helm global values

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm looking for best practice in Helm on when/when not to use global values.

I have a hostname that is required in 3 out of my 20 containers in kubernetes. Should I use a global value to allow all containers to access this value or just add it to the values for each required container?

```
global:
  networkPolicy:
    enabled: true
  hosts:
    url_1:"http://test.com"
    url_2:"http://test.com"
```

or

container 1,2,3

```
hosts:
    url_1:"http://test.com"
    url_2:"http://test.com"
```

If I could get some guidance on when to use global and when not to, that would help me a lot in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer using local values and then setting those values in deployment using something like ansible or the ci/cd pipeline.